# Fast HTTP downloads freeze frequently

Tags: windows, networking, download, http

I've been having a problem recently when it comes to downloading files with fast speeds (of any size) using HTTP.

The problem is mostly happening on a specific file-hosting site that I bought a premium account from. What happens is the download begins, but as the speed increases I'm suddenly no longer downloading any more MB's. The speed will usually freeze as well. The download doesn't cancel though, and if I pause and then resume it, data continues to download for a few more MB's, but then it freezes again. I have to do it continuously. If I leave it alone, it will eventually cancel the download. The issue happens with any browser, and it doesn't happen if I download as a free user. I also have similar issues on other sites where the speeds are very fast. Usually they'll cancel prematurely though or something similar. My connection isn't dying either, because I can browse and do other things while it's frozen.

I contacted the site's support and they said they don't throttle the speeds for premium, and that it must be an ISP issue. The only problem is that on Bittorrent I've gotten speeds up to 3 Mb/s without it freezing like that.

Primarily I use Firefox. I have Windows 7 professional on a Dell Inspiron laptop which is a few years old. My network card is Intel Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you use Linux (even as a LiveCD/USB) on the same PC and test? Also if possible test with a different PC using the same connection. What router/modem are you using?

Comment: I've tried it a couple times on a different computer and it doesn't seem to happen. I'm not absolutely convinced yet though. My router is a Linksys E3200 and my modem is a Motorola SB5101 Surfboard. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: This seems to me like a problem of the website. You can try to download a large file from another place (i.e. a Linux distro, they usually go in the GB range) to see if the issue will still be present.

Comment: @Max if you need to update your question, please use the [edit] button - you don't need to create a new question. Thanks.